# Questions about orthogonal subspace proof.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I'm having a hard time grasping this intuitively, much less showing how to prove it. Any help would be appreciated. I don't get why a vector orthogonal to a subspace would be in the space itself. How do I see/show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- At firt, $0\in S^\intercal$ because $\langle 0,v\rangle=0\,\forall v\in S\Rightarrow 0\in S^\intercal$
- In second place: if  $\,z\in S, \; u,v\in S^\intercal$ (it means $\langle u,z \rangle=\langle v,z \rangle=0$ for all $z\in S$) and $\mu,\lambda\in\mathbb{K}$, then: 
  $$\langle\lambda u +\mu v,z\rangle=\lambda\langle u,z\rangle + \mu\langle v,z\rangle=\lambda\times0+\mu\times0=0+0=0$$
  Then $\lambda u +\mu v\in S^\intercal$

$\therefore S^\intercal$ is a subspace of $V$

Comment: ohhhhh that makes sense, thank you